# Uploading files to IPFS in an Heroku Flask app

Tags: python, flask, heroku, ipfs

Good afternoon,
I have troubles with the IPFSHTTPCLIENT library for Python when uploading files to IPFS. It worked when I was running the app on a localhost environment. However, in Heroku, it doesn't, and I guess that it's because of the IP addresses. These are my current config variables and I don't know what should I put in order to make IPFS work again.

```
IPFS_CONNECT_URL = /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/5001/http
IPFS_FILE_URL = http://127.0.0.1:8080/ipfs/
```

Comment: Heroku only lets you bind to a single port and it's intended for handling HTTP requests. If you need multiple ports you'll have to find another host.